File not writable in localhost
I am using MAMP for Apache localhost server on a mac. I have a php code which adds username and password to the existing accounts.txt file. I have got a code to check if the file accounts.txt is writable and display in localhost if it is not writable, and as the localhost echoes "File is not writable". Both the php code file and accounts.txt are within the same folder directory. How can I resolve this permission issue?
I have tried to change the permission to htdocs for _www but then I am unable to edit the code in VScode within that. I am writing into the accounts.txt via file_put_contents($filename, $newaccounts, FILE_APPEND). I have tried fwrite() as well but it doesn't seem to be working resulting in the same writable issue.

Any data like that should be stored securely in a database, not in a text file in the website folder

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should separate code and data.
First, keep your htdocs folder non-writeable for the _www user. There is rarely a good reason to allow the PHP user to rewrite PHP files, and all you need is one server misconfiguration and any user data containing the string <?php eval($_GET['x']);?>, and now someone else has code execution on your server.
Second, put your data in a folder that is writeable for the _www user, but is outside of htdocs. You don't want your database to be accessible by any user just typing http://localhost/accounts.txt into their browser.
